# foreach array values into a single string

Tags: php, foreach

Im using PHP to output the category information from an RSS feed:

```
foreach(item_category()) as $category) { 
    $source = $category->cat_name; 
    echo $source.'.png';
}
```

Where `item_category` is an array of category names. I then have a set of corresponding images I've like to display against each item.

At the moment my output looks like this:

```
category1.pngcategory2.pngcategory3.png
```

but I need:

```
category1category2category3.png
```

How can I construct the correct file name with the single occurence of the file extension at the end of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach(item_category() as $category) { 
    $source = $category->cat_name; 
    echo $source;
}
echo'.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't use a local variable

```
echo implode('', array_map(function($c){
    return $c->cat_name;
}, item_category()) . '.png';
```

(Requires PHP >= 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(item_category() as $category)
    $source .= $category->cat_name;
echo $source.'.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(item_category()) as $category) { 
    $source .= $category->cat_name; 
}

echo $source'.png';
```

this should output

> cat1cat2cat3.png

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to put this line

```
echo $source.'.png';
```

Outside your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(item_category() as $category) { 
    echo $category->cat_name; 
}
echo '.png';
```